# Get collections in mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to get all the collection from a database in mongodb with PHP but I didn't find anything on internet useful.

This is what I get so far

```
$client = new MongoDB\client;
$database = $client->database2;
$collections = $database->listCollections();

foreach ($collections as $collection) {
    echo $collection;
}
```

I'm using `listCollections()` but doesn't work. I just need to get all data to show it.

This is my [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiBzM.png) if it helps

This is the output:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class MongoDB\Model\CollectionInfo could not be converted to string

Comment: And what is your output? What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: yes, sorry! I already edited the question.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Do not edit the word "solved" in to the question title. Accepting an answer is how you mark a question as successfully answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could do it with `getName()` to get all the collections name from my database.

```
$colecciones = $database->listCollections();
foreach ($colecciones as $col) {
    echo $col->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an object and you try to convert them to a string with an echo. So use `var_dump()` for example to make the object visible. Then you can use the methods to get more informations from the collection.

One of the methods is `getName()` you can use them to get the name of the collection.

[MongoDBModelCollectionInfo](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBModelCollectionInfo-getName/)

Comment: so how you would do it? because I'm still getting an error message with `getName()`
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getName()**

Comment: Make a var_dump on the `$collection` then look at the structure and then you can access the methods.

Comment: yes, but I mean how could I use `getName()`, to know the name of every collections.

Comment: This is what I get using var_dump of one of the collections

**object(MongoDB\Model\CollectionInfo)#24 (5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "medidor442" ["type"]=> string(10) "collection" ["options"]=> array(0) { } ["info"]=> array(2) { ["readOnly"]=> bool(false) ["uuid"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\Binary)#21 (2) { ["data"]=> string(16) "K�/|�Bߋ��Z��" ["type"]=> int(4) } } ["idIndex"]=> array(4) { ["v"]=> int(2) ["key"]=> array(1) { ["_id"]=> int(1) } ["name"]=> string(4) "_id_" ["ns"]=> string(20) "database2.medidor442" } }**

Comment: Try something like this: $collection->name